# Angular Unknown Provider ExpressJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am getting an unknown provider error.  My structure is set up with two different files, a controller file and a service file.  For some reason the angular app cannot find the service?  If I put the service within the same file it works fine?

controller file:

```
(function() {
  'use strict'
  angular
    .module('poke', ['ngResource'])
    .controller("appController", appController)

  appController.$inject = ['$scope', 'user']

  function appController($scope, user){
    $scope.saveUser = saveUser;

    // getProducts();
    //
    function saveUser(user_email) {
      return user.save({user_email}, function(data) {
        $scope.email = []
      });
    }
  }
})()
```

service file

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('poke')
    .factory("user", user)

    user.$inject = ['$resource']

    function user($resource) {
      return $resource("/users",{}, {})
    }
})();
```

html

```
<body ng-app="poke" ng-controller="appController" ng-cloak>
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Pokemon Go!</h1>
    </div>
    <form ng-submit="saveUser(email)" style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Please enter your email address to receive news about Pokemon Go in your city!</h3>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="example@email.com" ng-model="email"></input>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: Do you have a `<script>` tag referencing the .js file where you have defined the `user` service?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your main Module independently by injecting the global Dependencies. So you no need to refer this dependency in all files.

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource']);

    angular
        .module('poke')
        .controller("appController", appController)
```

then you can use **$resource** dependency across your angular components

Hope this helps

Comment: not sure what exactly you are recommending i do here :/